# Punctuation for a list of names in the middle of a sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas, lists, colons

> Under the direction of General Manager, Rian Wagner, a motivated project team, including: Edison Ven, Gary Bon, Justin Bembi, Marco Conch, Leo Bold and Richard Trolo, led the effort to bring the area up to the Inner Messa standard.

Is the punctuation in this sentence correct?  Should there be a comma at the end of the list (after "Rich Triolo")?

Comment: 'It might be useful to say when we [don't use a colon](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/colon.htm). Remember that the clause that precedes the mark (where you're considering a colon) ought to be able to stand on its own as an independent clause.' I'd drop the colon, drop the first comma (after 'Manager'), and leave the rest as it is. The comma you ask about is necessary to set off the parenthetical (including ... Trolo).

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the comma after "General Manager," so that the title and name run continuously as "General Manager Rian Wagner"—just as if you were instead writing "President Harry Truman."

I would also try to uncomplicate the rest of the punctuation by changing "including" to "composed of" or "consisting of." This minor change would enable you to get rid of the comma after "project team" and the one after "Richard Trolo." If you had to keep the word "including," you could avoid the potentially dizzying effects of comma glut by changing the comma after "project team" and the one after "Richard Trolo" to em dashes (—).

In any case, I would delete the colon, since it doesn't work satisfactorily in a situation where you want to indicate the beginning of an independent clause that doesn't run all the way to the end of the sentence.

Finally, it strikes me as a bit odd to talk about a team leading an effort under the direction (that is, leadership) of a leader not listed as a team member. You might finesse your way around that problem by changing "led" to something like "spearheaded."

That would leave you with this revised wording (and punctuation):

> Under the direction of General Manager Rian Wagner, a motivated project team consisting of Edison Ven, Gary Bon, Justin Bembi, Marco Conch, Leo Bold and Richard Trolo spearheaded the effort to bring the area up to the Inner Messa standard.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the colon and it'll be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not have a list in between, you would want a comma before including and before led.  Since there are commas within that middle clause, you need to use a different set of punctuation delimiters.

Under the direction of General Manager Rian Wagner, a motivated project team — including Edison Ven, Gary Bon, Justin Bembi, Marco Conch, Leo Bold, and Richard Trolo — led the effort to bring the area up to the Inner Messa standard.

or

Under the direction of General Manager Rian Wagner, a motivated project team (including Edison Ven, Gary Bon, Justin Bembi, Marco Conch, Leo Bold, and Richard Trolo) led the effort to bring the area up to the Inner Messa standard.

The "optional" Oxford Comma should not be optional (the comma before the last item of a list).  Not having it indicates that the two non-separated items are more closely associated than the rest or actually inseparable.  As for the comma after the last item of a list, it should not be there; if the sentence is not clear without it, then the whole list should be separated by other punctuation.  Sometimes you won't have just names in the list and just non-capitalized words outside of the list.